# Section subtitle or supplementary information that does not show up in TOC, references, ...?

Tags: sectioning, titles

I would like to have *optional* supplementary information (or subtitles) for sections that does not show up in TOC, references, ...

For example...

```
Some Title -- supplementary information
```

...or...

```
Some Title
Subtitle
```

...should *only* appear at the section's beginning, but TOC, references, ... should just show "*Some Title*" and nothing more.

Is there a command for this?

**EDIT**:

The ToC should just show:

```
1 Some Title
```

The beginning of the section should list all information, i.e. either:

```
Some Title -- supplementary information
```

or this way, realized with a subtitle:

```
Some Title
Subtitle
```

...but `\nameref` should only list the main title again. Thus...

```
See chapter \nameref{sec:sometitle} for more information.
```

...should show up as:

```
See chapter Some Title for more information.
```

So just `Some Title` everywhere, including ToC, `\nameref`, ..., but full information at the beginning of the section (and *only* there).

Comment: `\section[stuff for ToC]{Stuff that is not in ToC}` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the following?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[What shows in the TOC]{What shows at the start of the section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I'll try to edit and clarify the question.

Comment: @daniel451: Before saying "No", please test it. If you change `\section[What shows in the TOC]{What shows at the start of the section}` into `\section[Some Title]{Some Title -- supplementary information}` and add a `\label` and `\nameref` (using either package `hyperref` or `nameref`) , you'll should get exactly what you want. If not, please add a MWE to your question (as you should always do). Maybe this would show us, that you are using a class, that does not provide this standard feature in the same way.

Comment: In addition, if the answer I provided answered your initial question, please mark this question as answered and post a new question that better explains what it is you are looking for a solution to. Asking questions is free!